# Strange output when using tee in pipe command

Tags: linux, command-line, tee

I had to use the following command in an assignment:

```
who|tee test|wc -l
```

The output on my system is below, which implies that 2 users are connected:

```
2
```

Why is it I don't get the output of `who` on the screen, and right after that the output of `wc -l`? I thought `tee` wrote the output to the screen and created a file with the same output at the same time?

The output of `who` is however found in my file "*test*", but still it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of piping to `tee` is that whatever your first command writes to its [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) is written to a file (whose name you passed as a command-line argument to `tee`) as well as written to the standard output of the `tee` command. If the pipeline doesn't continue and you don't perform any redirections on the `tee` command, then `tee`'s standard output is that of your shell, usually your terminal.

That's why running `who` and running `who | tee test` show the same text on your terminal. The difference with `tee` you also write it to a file.

If the pipeline continues, as with `who | tee test | wc -l`, then whatever standard output would have been written to the terminal is sent to the next command in the pipeline instead. This is the `wc` command and, unlike `tee`, `wc` does not copy its input to standard output (or anywhere). Instead it shows statistics. With the `-l` option it shows just line counts, so that's all you see.

So the reason you see just `2` from `who | tee test | wc -l` is the same as the reason you see just `2` from `who | wc -l`. The `tee` command writes the output of `who` to a file but it does not cause it to be printed to the terminal unless *its* standard output is the terminal. By default it usually is, but not when you pipe it to yet another command.

If you've seen a command on the left side of a `|` whose output is displayed on the terminal rather than being used as input to the next command in the pipeline, then it likely was writing to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) instead of standard output.

Answer (score 1):

`tee` duplicates input so it goes to the file and *stdout*. From there *stdout* is piped to `wc`...it becomes *stdin* for `wc`. `wc` just returns counts, the input data it counts isn't echoed.

If you're trying to make sense of it you could think of `cmd1 | tee file | cmd2` as having the same effect as this:

```
cmd1 > file
cat file | cmd2
```

This isn't what *actually* happens but from the standpoint of the person executing the command they would appear to be the same (as long as `cmd1` is fast enough to give the impression that everything happens almost simultaneously). In reality `file` is being filled with data at the same time that `cmd2` is receiving that data.

Answer (score 0):

To see both `who` *and* `wc` outputs in `bash` do:

```
who | tee >(wc -l) test
```

Output:

```
me       tty7         2017-10-16 18:17 (:0)
1
```

Along with the contents of *test*.